# ERROR Closing socket for /127.0.0.1 because of error (kafka.network.Processor)

Tags: apache-camel, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm new to apache camel and apache kafka and doing a small POC for my project. I am getting following issue error log when trying to read from kafka using Camel-kafka component.

```
[2016-01-20 08:47:10,979] INFO Closing socket connection to /127.0.0.1. (kafka.network.Processor)
[2016-01-20 08:47:44,643] INFO Closing socket connection to /127.0.0.1. (kafka.network.Processor)
[2016-01-20 08:47:54,545] ERROR Closing socket for /127.0.0.1 because of error (kafka.network.Processor)
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:470)
    at kafka.api.TopicDataSend.writeTo(FetchResponse.scala:123)
    at kafka.network.MultiSend.writeTo(Transmission.scala:101)
    at kafka.api.FetchResponseSend.writeTo(FetchResponse.scala:231)
    at kafka.network.Processor.write(SocketServer.scala:472)
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:342)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My java code is as follows:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("kafka:127.0.0.1:9092?topic=TEST&zookeeperHost=localhost&zookeeperPort=2181&groupId=group1")
                    /*.marshal(xmlJsonFormat)*/
            .process(new XmlToJson())
                    /*.to("kafka:localhost:9092?topic=TestJson&zookeeperHost=localhost&zookeeperPort=2181&groupId=group1");*/
            .to("file:/Users/himanshu/Desktop/TransCamelFuse/test.txt");
        }
    });
    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    context.stop();
}
```

}

I've put some txt from kafka producer console tool and trying to read using camel component of kafka.

Answer (score 0):

It's not error.Giving this error because of your give data type. You are giving data to Kafka manually one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the kafka server and kafka client versions are compatible to each i faced the same my kafka server was 0.8 and some spring beans uses kafka 2.4 libraries so whenever 2.4 client request for any kafka 0.8 operation server.log record this error

**Solution** 
Be sure in code none of beans uses incompatible client for communication.